# Java Cloud Run Won't find file in resources folder

Tags: java, deployment, filesystems, google-cloud-run

My Java Springboot cloud run instance finds the files in my resources directory locally when I use
mvn clean spring-boot:run

but when I try to deploy to a cloud run instance it doesn't find the file. What's going on? Google's documentation is completely lacking and the examples don't cover this case. Not sure what's happening.

Obviously, the directory works because I have an application.properties file that's being read.

Folder structure

src

--main

----code

--resources

----application.properties

----kafka.properties

I also ran a func that traces the output of all the files in the dir for default "/" folder when trying to use a file and it just lists

myapp.jar
bin
dev
etc
home
lib
lib64
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var

so I think it's pointing to the wrong folder but I'm not sure why or how to change it.

Comment: when do you use `mvn package` and try run built jar on `java -jar your.jar` have you got successfully locally?

Comment: Yep it runs fine locally. even tested some hits to localhost with expected output.

Comment: Are you using Dockerfile to deploy into cloud run? Are you exposing you app.jar on 8080 port?

Comment: yeah so this all normally works. I'm just introducing a kafka producer to the codebase and it's erroring out on finding the keystore file.

Comment: Im using this line now: InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/kafka.properties"); 

to get the original file. but now it's not able to find the client truststore jks file.

Comment: I dont know I always have used this way too `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("  ");` may be something in image jdk version.  try get file with spring like this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access

Comment: so that works for the initial file but I call a keystore file within it that is now breaking and I can't figure out where in cloudrun instances its stored.

Comment: How do you build your container?

Comment: OK I figured it out. I add a line in the dockerfile to copy all the files in the resource folder over to a folder outside of the jar file and then have the scripts read those files like below. I'll be honest this doesn't seem like a full solution to me but it does the job.

COPY --from=builder /app/target/classes/client.truststore.jks /client.truststore.jks